# Picasso image loading library: how to load video thumbnails

Tags: android, video, picasso

I have some videos stored on device locally. And I'd like to use Picasso to handle video thumbnails also along with images. How I can do this?

Seems to be I just need to create my custom `Hunter` like `VideoHunter` and use them to create `Bitmap` from `InputStream`. But I didn't found any way to set my custom Hunter.

Or fork library and modify `BitmapHunter.forRequest`  is only way to handle video thumbnails in Picasso?

Comment: This would be good place to start.  https://github.com/square/picasso/pull/408

Comment: There is also a custom `RequestHandler` in Picasso 2.4.0 you can implement yourself to load these now.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid it's too late, but still: Glide library for Android is able to load video thumbnails just from URI/File, pretty much the same way as Images.

So all you need to do is:

```
Glide.with(Context)
     .load(videoFile) // or URI/path
     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Yep, also end up use Glide.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with a remote video file.

Comment: Glide loads only local Videos not URLs

Comment: This question was specifically for Picasso. This should be a comment.